# Find index of last true value in pandas Series or DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the index of the last True value in a pandas boolean Series.  My current code looks something like the below.  Is there a faster or cleaner way of doing this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

index = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 2), index=index)
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice([True, False], size=1000), index=index)

last_true_idx_s = s.index[s][-1]
last_true_idx_df = df[s].iloc[-1].name
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) what is the same as [argmax](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argmax.html) of Andy Hayden [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34385194/2901002):

```
print s[::-1].idxmax()
```

Comparing:

These timings are going to be very dependent on the size of s as well as the number (and position) of Trues - [thanks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384349/find-index-of-last-true-value-in-pandas-series-or-dataframe#comment56513446_34385309)

```
In [2]: %timeit s.index[s][-1]
The slowest run took 6.92 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 35 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit s[::-1].argmax()
The slowest run took 6.67 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 126 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit s[::-1].idxmax()
The slowest run took 6.55 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 127 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit s[s==True].last_valid_index()
The slowest run took 8.10 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 261 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit (s[s==True].index.tolist()[-1])
The slowest run took 6.11 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 239 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit (s[s==True].index[-1])
The slowest run took 5.75 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 227 µs per loop
```

EDIT:

Next solution:

```
print s[s==True].index[-1]
```

EDIT1: Solution

```
(s[s==True].index.tolist()[-1])
```

was in deleted answer.

Comment: isn't idxmax the same method?

Comment: What do you think? Why some of them is not removed from pandas? I am curious.

Comment: I think it *used* to be the case that `np.argmax` (and hence `.argmax`) would fall through to the pandas `.values` numpy array i.e. not return a Series. Now `np.argmax` returns a Series.

Comment: Up to you, though I would say for future answers: you should separate your timeit calls (that way it's easier to see which answer is for which call). :) That said, these timings are going to be very dependent on the size of s as well as the number (and position) of Trues.

Comment: Why is there such a large difference between the slowest and fastest runs?

Comment: Be aware that with idxmax the result is incorrect in case your Series doesn't contain any True.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html):

```
In [9]:
s.tail(10)

Out[9]:
h    False
w     True
h    False
r     True
q    False
b    False
p    False
e    False
q    False
d    False
dtype: bool

In [8]:
s[s==True].last_valid_index()

Out[8]:
'r'
```

Comment: This is the best solution. I think `last_valid_index` is clearer than `idxmax`.

Comment: I think this behavior is not intended: "If all elements are non-NA/null, returns None." `False` is non-null.

Answer (score 4):

[argmax](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argmax.html) gets the first True. Use argmax on the *reversed* Series:

```
In [11]: s[::-1].argmax()
Out[11]: 'e'
```

Here:

```
In [12]: s.tail()
Out[12]:
n     True
e     True
k    False
d    False
l    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I get timings of `1000 loops, best of 3: 638 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 284 µs per loop` comparing my method with yours +1

Comment: @EdChum one thing is a little annoying is that reversing creates a copy (IIUC)... you could drop to the values and use the numpy reversed view which may be slightly faster (but IMO much less readable) as essentially O(1).

Comment: @AndyHayden I guess that it's not immediately obvious why `argmax` works here, still it's quicker which is what usually counts

Comment: Yeah, it is at worst O(n) and short circuits. But it definitely does seem more magical (less descriptive).

Comment: Be aware that with this solution the result is incorrect in case your Series doesn't contain any True.